# Point of 64-bit programs?

Tags: operating-system

It seems like every program that I download has a 32-bit and a 64-bit version. Even small programs like notepad clones.

To my understanding, a 64-bit program can just access more than 4 gigs of memory versus 32-bit, so why do we want 64-bit versions of low-resource-consuming programs?

Comment: What if you want to open a 4GB file in a Notepad clone? (admittedly, not all of them can handle such large files, but I wish they could)

Comment: Not sure about any benefits - but at some point we **have to** migrate to 64 bit. Windows supported 16 bit programs up to Windows 7 32 bit (I believe?). But there comes the time to stop the support. As will for 32 bit.

Comment: @PhilippGrassl: windows removed 16bit support in the 64bit editions, so XP64, Vista64, the server versions, etc... all didn't have the 16bit subsystems anymore.

Comment: Dude - what programs are you downloading?  What OS are you running them on?  That would help intelligently answer your (somewhat apochryphal) question :)

Answer (score 1):

on Intel/Amd architectures, 64bit apps have access to more general purpose registers versus classic x86. Even if various bits of the code are naturally larger because they're using 64bit ints instead of 32bits, the extra registers can actually reduce code size by reducing the need for register juggling.

Even if a 64bit notepad doesn't make sense, it's still better to use the native OS api calls (e.g. the 64bit versions) rather than having to call through compatibility/translations layers to 32bit versions.